# Does eclipse milo support standard XML definded by the OPCUA-Foundation

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, opc-ua, milo

We want to import an XML File into the namespace of an OPC-UA Server, built by eclipse Milo. Is there any tool or example to do this? Does eclipse Milo support the standard data validation defined by the OPC-UA foundation? I mean these schemas:

```
   xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd" 

   xmlns:uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd" 

   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no utility to do this for you right now, but it's being worked on.

Comment: when is this expected to be finished?

Comment: Is this available in the meantime?